# Read Java Script function argument data type infomation

Tags: javascript, metadata, metaprogramming, sapui5

Is it possible to read a java script function arguments and their type information?

For example, i have a class below:

```
    sap.ui.define( ['sap/ui/core/theming/Parameters'],
            function(P){
                'use strict';
            var B=C.extend('sap.m.Button', { 
                            metadata:{
                                properties:{
                                text:{
                                    type:'string',
                                    group:'Misc',
                                    defaultValue:null
                                },
                                type:{
                                    type:'sap.m.ButtonType',
                                    group:'Appearance',
                                    defaultValue:sap.m.ButtonType.Default
                                }
                            }
                        } );
```

.....**B.prototype.setType=function(t){this.setProperty('type',t);**....

```
......lot of code exposes public setter & getter methods for the above properties.......
                        } );
```

Complete code of the class can be accessed from [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/m/Button.js).

I am able to read the method names from the public methods exposed by the class. But this does not allow me to know the arguments and their type information.

For example: ***B.prototype.setType*** is a public method exposed. I can acquire an object of Button class but not getting an idea of how to read its argument type info in run time.

If I want to let the user to add value for "type" property (it is button type), i should know the type of value he can enter.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Edit 1:

In my first step, i am using [getMetadata()](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Button.html#.getMetadata) method of sap.m.Button class which is exposed by the framework and this gives me the publicMethodNames but it does not give me information about argument type information. So, i am looking for alternatives.

In java, for this kind of need, we have reflection API. How can we achieve the same in javascript?

Edit 2:
A screenshot illustrating the result achieved in an IDE.

[image]

Comment: Code given is not enough to understand what you want. You can check the type of argument within the call of the function obviously, but the parameter is just a name placeholder until the function (method) is actually invoked, since JS is not a typed language.

Comment: Dellirium, Thanks for your comment. Added reference link of the actual class.

Comment: There is no reflection API that exposes type information, because there isn't any type information in the language. The best you can do is get that information elsewhere. For example if you know that setType for a Button expects an argument to have a value from some list, you might be able to discover where that list is defined in the framework code.

Comment: @artem: If i know what a method expects in its arguments, i should be able to create the respective objects. But my challenge is to find what a method (e.g. setType) accepts. The similar thing is done in Web IDE but for a different purpose. I have added a screenshot.

Comment: Oh. It looks like that framework is documented: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Button.html#setType , and such kind of documentation is typically generated from some source. If so, you can try to find out how doc generator (or that IDE) works and where it gets that information.

Answer (score 1):

You can access to function parameters with `arguments` object:

```js
var f = function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i], typeof arguments[i]);  
  }
}

f(123, 'test', { a: 1}, function () { alert('x') });
```

**UPD** How to get declared arguments number:

```js
var f = function (a, b) {
  console.log(arguments); 
};

console.log(f.length); //2
f(1, 1, 1, 1); //object with 4 keys
f(1); //object with 1 key
```

Comment: Digger2000: Thanks for your reply. I could not understand your suggestion. The function of the class is coming from the framework. I cannot modify the function to log "arguments" information. How can i access the function argument type information from outside the function and class is my question. In java, i can look into classes and methods and their arguments using reflection API. Is similar thing possible in javascript? Thanks

Comment: Functions in JavaScript haven't fixed arguments list, they can be called with any arguments. However, you can access declared arguments number:

var f = function (a, b) { /* code */};  console.log(f.length);

//2

Comment: That's nice. I need arguments and thier types too so that i let the user enter valid information.

Comment: I think your question is relates more to the framework than to the JavaScript itself.

Comment: Framework is of not much help here. That's why i am trying to see if i can get a solution from language capabilities!! Any other solution you can think of?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't.